# Casting a list during a stream operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Here's my scenario:

```
private List<Entity> getPlanets() {
   return entities.values()
                  .stream()
                  .filter(x -> x instanceof Planet)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

- `Entity` is the super class of `Planet`
- entities is a `HashMap<Entity>`
- As the method is called "getPlanets" I would like it to return a `List<Planet>` but it appears to me that the stream expression is going to return a `List<Entity>`
- I tried some casting expressions but none seem to work out.

I am brand new with Java 8 streams so maybe someone can point out what I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return entities.values()
               .stream()
               .filter(x -> x instanceof Planet)
               .map(x -> (Planet) x)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Fastest answer from SO ever! Thanks :)

Comment: @pitosalas - you can accept this answer if it answers your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

A variation with method references:

```
return entities.values().stream()
    .filter(Planet.class::isInstance)
    .map(Planet.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```